# Watir-Webdriver Control Android ChromeDriver on Android Device

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I downloaded ChromeDriver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads and put it in my `platform-tools` folder within the Android SDK folder. I have my phone connected and it appers to be setup correcly, when I run `./chromedriver` it says

```
$ ./chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

However how do I make Watir connect to it? I tried the following, but it just opens a local desktop browser instead of a browser on the Android device.

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://localhost:9515")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [ChromeDriver's Getting Started page for Android](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android), you need to specify the androidPackage Chrome option.

The Ruby and Watir equivalent of their example would be:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  "chromeOptions" => { "androidPackage" => "com.android.chrome" }
)
@browser = Watir::Browser.new(
  :remote,
  :url => "http://localhost:9515",
  :desired_capabilities => caps
)
```